# Select single row of Flatlist React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Hey guys Im making a custom size picker I want to select single size at a time but onPress all item got changed..

my onPress event

```js
onPressItemSize = (item,index:string) => {
  this.setState((item) => {
    const xl =
    xl == item ? this.setState({xl:true}) : this.setState({xl:false});
    return { xl };
  });
  this.setState({selectedSize:item.value})
};
```

and this is my flatlist component

```js
<FlatList
  data={this.state.label}
  numColumns={5}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
  extraData={this.state}
  renderItem={({item,index}) =>
    <View style={{padding:10,}}>
      <TouchableOpacity 
        onPress={this.onPressItemSize.bind(this, item,index)}
        style={[styles.Buttoncolor,this.state.xl?null:styles.onfocusbutton]}>
        <Text adjustsFontSizeToFit 
          textTransform='uppercase' 
          style={[styles.textcolor,this.state.xl?null:styles.white]}>
          {item.label}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
   }
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure which state are you trying to set but you need to keen in mind that calling `setState` will trigger an async function and you need to wait until the new state is successfully changed. i would also use arrow functions for not binding the functions when calling them.

```
onPressItemSize = (item, index) => {

  const { xl } = this.state;  //what is xl ?? im assuming it is in your state
  const callback = () => {console.log("State changed");}

  var newXL = false;

  if(xl === item){
    newXL = true
  }

  //you can set diferents values at the same time
  this.setState({xl: newXL, selectedSize: item.value }, callback)

};



<FlatList
  data={this.state.label}
  numColumns={5}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
  extraData={this.state}
  renderItem={({item, index}) =>
    <View style={{padding:10,}}>
      <TouchableOpacity 
        onPress={() => onPressItemSize(item, index)}     //changed
        style={[styles.Buttoncolor,this.state.xl?null:styles.onfocusbutton]}>
        <Text adjustsFontSizeToFit 
          textTransform='uppercase' 
          style={[styles.textcolor,this.state.xl?null:styles.white]}>
          {item.label}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
   }
/>
```

Comment: I guess OP wants to make one of his buttons bigger (or othewise selected) with XL state (from extra large??) but then he should store selected index in the state and make styles according it.